# Get the Google Analytics page views for a directory

Tags: google-analytics, home-directory

I have a blog network set up with the following schema:

Blogs:

- example.com/blog-1/
- example.com/blog-2/
- example.com/blog-3/

Posts:

- example.com/blog-1/great-post.html
- example.com/blog-1/cool-post.html
- example.com/blog-1/alright-post.html
- example.com/blog-2/awesome-post.html
- example.com/blog-2/interesting-post.html
- example.com/blog-2/dull-post.html
- example.com/blog-3/another-post.html
- example.com/blog-3/favorite-post.html

I'm trying to get active page views in Google Analytics for each blog, so all example.com/blog-1/*.

To this, I created an advanced segment in Analytics:
*Page* starts with */blog-1/*

This works, but it also pulls in any page on my site that links to that blog. Any suggestions to just get pages with those blogs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Content > Content Drilldown` in the analytics interface allows you to show all the pageviews for a path or group of paths (it recognizes slashes as delimiters).

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the simplest way. I was getting used to the advanced segments, but I don't believe you can do advanced segments with content drilldown, can you?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but I haven't played much with segmenting.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up separate tracking code for each blog. It will be easier to see how each blog performs.

Look here: http://www.webfuel.ca/gic to see what Google recommends